# Soundbar 30" or under that doesn't have low volume dialog problems

Tags: audio, sound-system

I need a soundbar 30" or under that doesn't have low volume dialog problems [often seen in low end 2 channel systems & TV's](https://www.google.com/search?q=dialog%20too%20quiet%20tv&oq=dialog%20too%20quiet%20tv).

The smallest 3 Channel system I could find is the [Vizio 3.0-Channel Soundbar with Bluetooth and Deep Bass Technology - Black SB3830-C6M](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00Z2XXEKI) which shouldn't have the problem but it's 38".

At minimum it just needs to have Digital SPDIF Input for I/O.

No additional external system components (sub-woofer, satellite speakers, etc).

The soundbar will be mounted right below the TV using a TV soundbar mounting bracket. The TV is on a wall mount.

Comment: what is your budget by the way?

Comment: As low as meets the minimum spec but if there is a limited selection I'll have to make do.

Comment: Also, are you looking for a specific number of channels?

Comment: If the driver is capable of managing dialog volume properly with < 3 channels than that would be sufficient. I'm basing my bias on how all my 2 channel stereo TV's fail to properly drive the center channel dialog volume through the built in speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one looks like it meets your requirements in terms of size and dialog volume: https://www.bose.com/en_us/products/speakers/home_theater/bose-solo-5-tv-sound-system.html

- Has mounting brackets
- Has "Dialogue mode to hear each word and detail clearly"
- Has Optical audio input (digital)
- Is < 30" (21.6")

Comment: Wow I'm surprised a Bose product didn't come up in any of my searches... That looks like it might work.

Comment: I had seen that, but couldn't find it anywhere lol. Assumed it was discontinued...scuse me while i go look for a wall to bash my head against

Answer (score 1):

Edit: 11/14/16

How about something like this? [Sony HT-XT3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IWQREOE)

This is actually a soundbase, which sits under the TV....but it does fit the rest of the specs as far as width....Finding a match for your specifications, is being tedious lol.

Here is a [review](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/tvs-entertainment/soundbars/1404104/sony-ht-xt3-review) if it helps

Comment: Close - amended the question to include specifically that I want to avoid any additional external system components (sub-woofer) to reduce cost.

Comment: The Sony `HT-XT3` unfortunately won't work as the TV is wall mounted and there is no traditional TV stand or mounting space. Tedious - yes - hence the bounty :) It may be wiser just to buy a new TV that has a better built in audio driver.

Comment: I ended up giving up on finding decent PC speakers, well, more like dual use home theater AND PC speakers, just caved and got a home theater receiver, and am using bookshelf speakers, albeit some good old ones from the late 70s, to mid 80s.  Built my own TV stand, using  some threaded rods, matching diameter bolts/washers, and a hand drill.   Sad, that the best thing I learned in High School was how to make random crap outta wood.